# installing PDFLib to PHP 5.3 on Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard, pdflib

I'm trying to install PDFLib (http://www.pdflib.com/) into Apache/Joomla running on my Mac OSX 10.6 pc.  The procedure I've followed is:

1. copy /PDFlib-7.0.5/bind/php5/php-530/libpdf_php.so to: /usr/lib/php/extensions/libpdf_php.so
2. add to php.ini: extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/libpdf_php.so
3. change permissions on the executable: chmod a+rwx libpdf_php.so
4. restart Web Sharing in System Preferences

when I look at php_info() I don't see a section for PDFLib, and I cant see any errors in Console.
Any clues what else to check?

Comment: You could check if you edited the right php.ini file. You could also check if you actually do error logging and if so, then check the error log. Otherwise enable error logging.

Comment: by enabling logging I found this message: [08-Jan-2012 17:04:44] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/libpdf_php.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/libpdf_php.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/lib/php/extensions/libpdf_php.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

Try installing php and pdflib with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/#install):

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php53
brew install php53-pdflib
```

Edit this file:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/5.3/conf.d/ext-pdflib.ini
```

Change `pdflib.so` to `pdf.so`

Answer (score 0):

apparently the solution is to use the 10.5 binaries: http://www.pdflib.com/binaries/PDFlib/705/PDFlib-7.0.5-MacOSX-10.5-Universal-php.dmg